# rsync to backup a multi-user NAS

Tags: rsync

The setup :

- a Ubuntu server with samba shares to 25 users all with Windows (different locales).
- the Ubuntu server then has a daily cron job executed as `Admin` (not `root`) running rsync to backup the shared folders to a Synology NAS. the report of this sync is sent by email.
- the Synology NAS is mounted through `/etc/fstab` on the Ubuntu server using the `admin` account credentials, the rsync is from local folder to mounted folder.

Here my `/etc/fstab` line

```
//192.168.0.30/NetBackup /mnt/SynologyNAS/NetBackup cifs credentials=/home/admin/.nascredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw 0 0
```

The problem : I have quite a few files that are copied everyday, generating a 2MB report email instead of few kB. those files are those who have a owner that is not admin.

For instance :

- `Admin` creates a file in the samba-shared folder `Public`, it will then be backed up by the cron job. The owner of the file in the backup folder is `Admin`. Following day, no copy happens.
- `UserNotAdmin` creates a file in the samba-shared folder `Public`, it will then be backed up by the cron job. The owner of the file in the backup folder is `Admin`. Following day, copy happens again, and so on.

Here is my rsync line

```
rsync -av --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --delete /share/localFolder/ /mnt/SynologyNAS/NetBackup/remoteFolder
```

I also already tried

```
rsync -avO --delete /share/localFolder/ /mnt/SynologyNAS/NetBackup/remoteFolder
```

and

```
rsync -vrltD --delete /share/localFolder/ /mnt/SynologyNAS/NetBackup/remoteFolder
```

How to setup everything so that they are copied once and for all?

Answer (score 0):

Your `rsync` job is not preserving owner/group information. Please add the `-a` parameter to your `rsync` command (eg: using `rsync -av <src> <dst>`)

Comment: I am already using that.

Comment: Can you show the full rsync command?